# Access a Method's Attribute from OnActionExecuting

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-mvc-filters

I was wondering how can I check if a Controller Method has a certain attribute, for example `AllowAnonymous`, inside `OnActionExecuting` override method.

I've tried with this:

```
var methodAttr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(context.ActionDescriptor.GetType(), typeof(AuthorizeAttribute));
```

But I always get a Null value.

Tried also with this:

```
MethodBase method = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
AuthorizeAttribute methodAttr = (AuthorizeAttribute)method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AuthorizeAttribute), true)[0];
```

But when there is not AuthorizeAttribute I get an out of range exception.

How can I do this check?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming based on your tags that this is for .net core.
Here is an example of checking for a custom attribute

```
var descriptor = (ControllerActionDescriptor) context.ActionDescriptor;
if (descriptor.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttribute<AuthorizeAttribute>() != null) { 
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: For simplicity => `descriptor.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttribute<AuthorizeAttribute>() != null`

Comment: Just remember that we can also do this => `descriptor.MethodInfo.IsDefined(typeof(AuthorizeAttribute))`. I like it because here we don't need the value of the custom attribute. Sorry for double comments :)